# Add data to firebase and redirect to other page simultaneously

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a website with login/signUp feature with **Firebase**, the problem is that when User Creates a new Account I want to redirect him to the homepage and put his name in **firebase database** simultaneously. The User gets redirected to the homepage and I cannot add data to **firebase database**

Please Check my Code

```
signUp.addEventListener('click',() => {

const emailValue = emailField.value;
const passValue = passField.value;

if(emailValue === "" && passValue === "" || emailValue !== "" && passValue    == "" || emailValue == "" && passValue !== "") 
{
    alert('Please fill all fields')
}
else {
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailValue,passValue);
    promise
    .then(() => {
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailValue,passValue);
        let userId = auth.currentUser.uid;
        let dataRef = firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId);
        dataRef.set({
            name: nameField.value
        });
        console.log('User Signed In');
        return './homepage.html';
    })
    .then((address) => {
        window.location.href = address;
    })
    .catch(e => {
    console.log(e.message);
    })

}

});
```

Thanks In Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createUserWithEmailAndPassword` returns an `user object` so there is no need to to re-validate credentials. Please try this:

```
signUp.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const emailValue = emailField.value;
  const passValue = passField.value;
  if (emailValue === "" && passValue === "" || emailValue !== "" && passValue == "" || emailValue == "" && passValue !== "") {
    alert('Please fill all fields')
  } else {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailValue, passValue).then(function (user) {
      const user_data = {
        wo: 0
      };
      const promise = firebase.app().database().ref(`/users/${user.uid}`).set(user_data);
      promise.then(() => {
        setTimeout(1000);
        window.location.href = './homepage.html';
      });
    }, function (error) {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log(errorMessage);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I thought it was included in the question, just removed ;)

Comment: Also it would be usefull to add an explenation about what you changed/added and why it will help.

Comment: @AndréKool just added a description, thanks for the comments

Comment: Thanks alot @d.mares for the answer just had to change your code a little bit

`const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
const promise = firebase.app().database().ref(`/users/${userId}`).set(user_data);`

**${user.uid}** in your code was resulting in undefinded in firebase databas